# jQuery Autocomplete used as a search bar with redirect in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using the jQuery Autocomplete widget to try to search for groups within a social media site. There are two types of groups and I am using the example code from the jQuery website to make categories as in this link

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Each item in the table therefore has a category, a label and a value. The value is the id of the group.

What I want to be able to do is that when I click on an item in the list that I've searched, to be redirected to a different controller depending on the group category.

In your answer items with a category of `typeA` should be redirected to the controller `fooA` and those with a category of `typeB` should be redirected to the controller `fooB`.

My jQuery

```
$('#searchBar').catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term);
        response(results.slice(0, 10));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this one out on my own after a bit of tinkering around. It's not exactly what I wanted or had in mind but it does the job.

I added the urls to the value attribute of each item in the dataset and then used `window.location.href` to redirect the window to the appropriate controller and function.

I hope this helps other people but if you do know a way to do this using the Codeigniter function `redirect`, I'd really appreciate it